# Ruby on Rails: Use existing Model if possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relational-database

I want to create a relationship from recipe to ingredients. Basically:

```
recipe has_many ingredients
ingredients belongs_to recipe
```

But if I add a ingredient to a recipe it should look if there is an existing ingredient with the same name and should use that one.

Is there a smooth solution?

Comment: did you try to use HABTM-relation?

Comment: I thought this wont use existing childs ( ingredients ) on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having all realations set up in a standart way (HABTM) you could add ingrediants by name like this:

```
# reciept.rb
def add_ingredient_by_name(ingredient_name)
  self.ingredients << Ingredient.find_or_create_by(name: ingredient_name)
end
```

**Update:**
Also I'd add a uniqueness constraint for ingredient name for safety:

```
# ingredient.rb
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

Comment: That would be pretty nice. But what will be the create method for ingredient ?
`@recipe.ingredients.add_ingredient(params[:something])` will not work, wont it?

Comment: Well, simply `@recipe.add_ingredient(params[:something])`

Comment: @orgertot, (just updated with more appropriate method name)

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand your schema out:  you need to differentiate between an ingredient like "all purpose flour", of which you want one in your database, and then "100 grams of all purpose flour" which might be used in a specific recipe.

I would do something like this:

```
Recipe
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  #fields - name

RecipeIngredient
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe
  #fields - quantity

Ingredient
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  #fields - name
```

Now, when you build a recipe, you're building a list of associated `recipe_ingredients`, each of which points to an ingredient (like the "all-purpose flour" ingredient) and has a quantity, eg "100 grams".

Note - i could have added "has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients" to Recipe, but i don't actually think this is a useful association:  ingredients only make sense for the recipe when they have a quantity - i don't think you would ever want to say "recipe.ingredients" as this doesn't give you the quantity info.

Comment: I want to expand your example: if I add a new ingredient to a new recipe it should look up if there is the same ingredient by name and should link to that one though RecipeIngredient

Comment: That's not an expansion, that's exactly how it's supposed to work.  You would only ever have one "all purpose flour" ingredient in the "ingredients" table, and recipe ingredients using all purpose flour point to that.

Comment: But is that not sooo much complicated if i have a show on recipe and just want to add a ingredient without recipeingredient ? The recipe thing is just an example. So you could have ingredients without quantity at first. so it should be create/open recipe => create/use existing ingredient

Comment: 3 models?  Complicated?  I wouldn't say so.  Having ingredients without quantity in a recipe doesn't make sense: there's no point trying to start with a nonsensical situation and then change it later.  You might as well start with the situation which makes sense.  Can you imagine looking at a recipe in which the ingredients list says "caster sugar, all-purpose flour, eggs, bananas, vanilla essence"?  The first thing you would think would be "err, it's missing the quantities".